# Bind click event to dynamically generated content (Angular 4)

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker

I have the following function that basically generates a date and inserts it before a div in a view - I need to modify this so I am able to use a click event using the angular renderer function but having difficulties with the code below:

```
generateTimestampDiv(date, $this) {
    let parent = document.getElementsByClassName('ui-datepicker-header');
    let minutes = (date.getMinutes()<10 ? '0' : '') + date.getMinutes();
    let datetime = date.toDateString()+' '+date.getHours()+':'+minutes;

    let content = '<div style="background-color: #fafafa; width:90%;">'+ datetime +'</div>';
    $(content).insertBefore(parent[0]);

    // this bit is incorrect
    this.renderer.listen(content, 'click', (event) => {
        this.userClicked(event, this);
    })
}
```

I need to modify the function to insert the content as per the function but also listen for a click event event so that I can pass the event to the userClicked() function

Comment: Why don't you use the Angular way, which would be `{{ datetime }}` in your component template ?

Comment: Also, if you need special date formatting, take a look at the DatePipe : https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 1):

Use the Angular Renderer2 insertBefore method

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('clickablediv') el: ElementRef;

  constructor(private _renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._renderer.listen(this.el.nativeElement, 'click', (event) => {
      this.generateTimestampDiv(new Date())
    });
  }

  generateTimestampDiv(date) {
    let minutes = (date.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + date.getMinutes();
    let datetime = date.toDateString() + ' ' + date.getHours() + ':' + minutes;

    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.backgroundColor = "#fafafa";
    div.style.width = "90%";
    div.innerHTML = datetime;

    this._renderer.insertBefore(this.el.nativeElement.parentNode, div, this.el.nativeElement)
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m2b1tb)